# eliminate duplicate code for similar function definitions

Tags: c++, networking, refactoring, c++14, code-reuse

I've a method which is composed of some logic + an underlying system call. Now another method which contain exactly similar logic but only the underlying system call changes, has to be implemented.

I'm trying to think of some way to reuse the common code and implement another method which might take a callable to call the underlying system call but haven't been successful since the airty of `read` and `recv` calls are different.

Would be great to find an elegant solution about the same. The methods look like -

---

**First Function**

```
std::string Socket::read(const int bufSize) const
{
    auto buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(bufSize + 1);
    auto recvd = 0, count = 0;

    std::string str;
    str.reserve(bufSize);

    do {

        // ONLY THIS PART IS DIFFERENT
        recvd = ::read(sockfd, buffer.get() + count, bufSize - count);
        // ONLY THIS PART IS DIFFERENT

        count += recvd;
        if (count == bufSize) {
            str.append(buffer.get());
            str.reserve(str.length() + bufSize);
            std::memset(buffer.get(), 0, bufSize);
            count = 0;
        }
    } while (recvd > 0);

    str.append(buffer.get(), count);

    if (recvd == -1) {
        // TODO: Check for recvd == EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK and
        // don't throw exception in that case.
        throw std::runtime_error("Error occurred while writing message");
    }

    return str;
}
```

---

**Second Function**

```
std::string Socket::recv(const int bufSize, SF::recv flags) const
{
    auto buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(bufSize + 1);
    auto recvd = 0, count = 0;

    std::string str;
    str.reserve(bufSize);

    do {

        // ONLY THIS PART IS DIFFERENT
        const auto f = static_cast<int>(flags);
        recvd = ::recv(sockfd, buffer.get() + count, bufSize - count, f);
        // ONLY THIS PART IS DIFFERENT

        count += recvd;
        if (count == bufSize) {
            str.append(buffer.get());
            str.reserve(str.length() + bufSize);
            std::memset(buffer.get(), 0, bufSize);
            count = 0;
        }
    } while (recvd > 0);

    str.append(buffer.get(), count);

    if (recvd == -1) {
        // TODO: Check for recvd == EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK and
        // don't throw exception in that case.
        throw std::runtime_error("Error occurred while writing message");
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the code is supposed to do? I get the basic gist, but I think there are probably easier and shorter ways to implement both.

Comment: Though I should mention that the easy way would be to simply split the function logic into different functions. Nothing earth-shattering.

Comment: @tambre reads from `<sys/socket.h> socket` and returns a `std::string`.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal If you have working code already, the better place to ask for improvement and refactoring might be [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also splitting out the identical parts in your code to separate functions should help to avoid DRY.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ should I delete this post then, or is there some way to migrate it to SE Code Review?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal You probably meant _question_. But yes, delete here and repost at that other site (Just preserve and improve the markup you have here). Cross posting isn't well achieved,

Comment: Recommend a read of the help page on asking questions  for code review before posting and ensure you meet their rules or you'll likely get bounced back here.

Comment: I'll just keep it here since it is a valid post for SO too.

Comment: You haven't marked it as such, but the declaration and usage of `flags` and `f` is also another difference between the second function and the first.

Comment: Also, your question is miss-tagged as C++11.   `std::make_unique` was introduced in C++14.

Comment: @Peter edited. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++14 you can do it this way. This is a more flexible solution, although this is not designed to suit your exact need. And as a result, it can turn out to be less expressive.

```
#include <utility>

namespace detail {

template <class Fn, class... Args>
auto DuplicatedCode(Fn &&fn, Args&&... args) {
  // some code

  // auto result =
  std::forward<Fn>(fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

  // more code

  // return
}

}

void foo() {
  detail::DuplicatedCode([](){return 0;});
}

void bar() {
  detail::DuplicatedCode([](){return 1;});
}
```

You can declare some local variables in foo and bar, and `DucplicatedCode` will forward them to `fn` or you can simply capture those variables.

Comment: This is very good method imho, is it also the example for perfect forwarding, right? Would you mind checking - http://ideone.com/WNm35N, if this is intended usage of your solution.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Lambda expression is not necessary here, you get this point, you get the whole idea : ). You can also modify the call to fn if needed (pass some local variable in DuplicatedCode etc..)

Answer (score 3):

When I'm going to compare your versions of `std::string Socket::read(const int bufSize) const` and `std::string Socket::recv(const int bufSize, SF::recv flags) const`

[image]
the only difference is

```
const auto f = static_cast<int>(flags);
```

and

```
recvd = ::recv(sockfd, buffer.get() + count, bufSize - count, f);
```

Thus your 1st version could be refactored to a call of the 2nd version using a specific set of *`flags`*.

Or you could provide a default value for `flags` like

```
 std::string Socket::recv(const int bufSize, SF::recv flags = DefaultFlags) const
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to sum the methods and pass an invalid flag, if the read message is called:

```
if(flags==INVALID)
        recvd = ::read(sockfd, buffer.get() + count, bufSize - count);
    else
        recvd = ::recv(sockfd, buffer.get() + count, bufSize - count, f);
```

BUT, this will violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), because the method has now two responsibilities and two reasons to change.

A better solution will be to extract the common parts of both methods.

```
read() {
 commonMethod1();
 ::read();
 commonMethod2();
} 
write() {
 commonMethod1();
 ::read();
 commonMethod2();
}
```

How ever, your question is maybe based on different opinions, but this one is mine. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to add a private helper function within the `Socket` class

```
class Socket
{
     // everything else you already have

     private:

        std::string recv_helper(int bufSize, const SF::recv *flags = nullptr) const;
              // note the second argument is a pointer  
};
```

and implement it as

```
std::string Socket::recv_helper(int bufSize, const SF::recv *flags) const
{
     //   All the code preceding your first // ONLY THIS PART IS DIFFERENT

     if (flags)
     {
         recvd = ::recv(sockfd, buffer.get() + count, bufSize - count,
                        static_cast<int>(*flags));
     }
     else
     {
         recvd = ::read(sockfd, buffer.get() + count, bufSize - count);
     }

      //   All the code following your second // ONLY THIS PART IS DIFFERENT    
}
```

Then all you need to do is reimplement your two functions to call the helper.

```
std::string Socket::read(int bufSize) const
{
    return recv_helper(bufSize);
}

std::string Socket::recv(int bufSize, SF::recv flags) const
{
    return recv_helper(bufSize,  &flags);
}
```

Note that I have also removed the redundant `const` qualifier from arguments passed by value.